# No order information if products is virtual?

Tags: virtual-products

I have added virtual products to a webshop for the first time, and afterwards i created an order with the virtual product.
But when I click on the order in the back-end I can't get any information about the order. Is this normal? Please see my screenshot below;
[image]

Comment: Please check your magento and apache log, and post your findings here, this is clearly due to an error.

Comment: In what file should I look in? And is there something specific I should look for in it? :)

Comment: var/log/system.log and (probably) /var/log/apache2/error.log, tail those files and see if something is added when you hit the order page that does not work

Comment: I guess the problem should be in shipping address customization if you did any, as virtual products don't have shipping address object.

Comment: I have a module that integrates with our shipping supplier and makes it easy to setup rates. Could this be the problem?
Sadly my system.log is incredible big. Is there any keywords i can search for?

Comment: I have no apache2 folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a broken page. There might be a module causing this since this is not the default Magento behaviour. You should check your logs under var/log and inside your apache logs to see what is causing this issue.